# Listview update is not working after calling notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: java, android, listview

Listview update is not working after calling notifyDataSetChanged.  The user clicks on a build and I update the data but the screen never gets updated?  can someone please tell me why maybe the load data is not working?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


      list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
      list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));

      final EditText EditMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextWebSite);
      Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String website = EditMessage.getText().toString();

                //String returnString = loaddata(website);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),
                        "Updating Information",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                setListData();

                BaseAdapter la = (BaseAdapter)list1.getAdapter();
                ((BaseAdapter) la).notifyDataSetChanged() ;

                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),
                        "Updated",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

            }
        });



private void setListData()
    {
        String array2[] = { "Iphone", "Tutorials", "Gallery", "Android",    "item 1", "item 2", "item3", "item 4" };
         System.arraycopy(array, 0, array2, 0, array.length);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
((ArrayAdapter)list1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged() ;
```

instead of casting to BaseAdapter.

Comment: nothing.. maybe its the setListData that is not working?? private void setListData() { String array2[] = { "Iphone", "Tutorials", "Gallery", "Android", "item 1", "item 2", "item3", "item 4" }; System.arraycopy(array, 0, array2, 0, array.length); }

Comment: You have misplaced source and destination in arraycopy. chane array to array2 and array2 to array. and array.length to array2.length

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

final ArrayAdapter mArrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
      list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
      list1.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);

      final EditText EditMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextWebSite);
      Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String website = EditMessage.getText().toString();

                //String returnString = loaddata(website);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),
                        "Updating Information",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                setListData();

                mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() ;

                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),
                        "Updated",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

            }
        });
```

try this out may helps

Comment: nothing.. maybe its the setListData that is not working??    private void setListData()
    {
     String array2[] = { "Iphone", "Tutorials", "Gallery", "Android", "item 1", "item 2", "item3", "item 4" };
      System.arraycopy(array, 0, array2, 0, array.length);
    }

Answer (score 1):

I found the listener method may not run on the UI main thread. You should make sure when you use

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

in the UI main thread.So you can use **hander** to resolve this problem.